# master / detail problem with dbexpress

Tags: delphi, firebird, dbexpress

I have a master / detail application written in Delphi 2010 / dbExpress using firebird 2.3
I have found a problem

If I have two or three or more identical lines of data in the detail, changing any data in one of them also changes the data on the other lines, I guess this is because the update uses only the invoice_id and serial as keys and the data is equal in both cases, the update is done in the two cases.

Master Data
Invoice_id, serial, customer_id, date
1, A, 1.12 / 12 / 2010

Detail Data
Invoice_id, serial, qty, description, Price
1, A, 10, BOXES OF SOME STUFF, 52.52
1, A, 10, BOXES OF SOME STUFF, 52.52

I guess I can fix this by using a field ltes name ir line_no in which each line would have a different number and so the data could be distinguished to make the update as follows:

Line_no, Invoice_id, serial, qty, description, Price
1.1, A, 10, BOXES OF SOME STUFF, 52.52
2.1, A, 10, BOXES OF SOME STUFF, 52.52

So the information is the same but it has also the  line_no to differentiate the information in the update

Anyone know any way to do this on the client side, in the clientdataset,

Thank you very much and greetings

Comment: If both rows are identical, dbexpress and the 99% of the data connection layers for 99% of the languages/frameworks will face problems updating it, because there's no standard way to write a update statement to change only one of the rows and not both at a time, so change your design and define a primary key, it is a good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no primary key in your detail table (assuming invoice_id is the foreign key to the master table. To make sure that FireBird (or any dbExpress connected database) updates the correct record you should add a primary key (autoinc field) to the detail table.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem, the client does not know the autoinc value because it is generated on the server, I need to generate some kind of value form the client side like a line number or something that diferentiates the values in the detail table

Comment: Once the lines are added on the client and committed to the server they should have an ID that you can use to update them. I don't see how you can not have an ID?